# Install ROS Package Globally

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if it was possible to install a ROS package from source globally via `catkin_make install`? i.e., I would want the package installed into the /opt/ros/indigo/... location instead of the catkin workspace. The use case is for a package not in the build farm that we wanted all users on our robot to have access to.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189492/install-ros-package-globally/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can change the install location as for any CMake project (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX) by passing:

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/your/install/path
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Panzarella](https://answers.ros.org/users/255/tom-panzarella/) on 2015-04-24**:
This had been working for me historically. However, it seems as of late catkin is not respecting the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX option. Is this a regression? I'm running the latest version of Indigo as of 4/24/15.

**Comment by [Tom Panzarella](https://answers.ros.org/users/255/tom-panzarella/) on 2015-04-24**:
OK. I have this sorted out now. It seems as though you need to specify the `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when calling the `install` target instead of at compile time, which is what used to work. No big deal, just unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`/opt/ros/indigo` is managed by the package manager, and it may overwrite files and directories there at any time, so I don't recommend installing packages into `/opt/ros/indigo`. (conversely, if the package manager finds files there that it isn't managing, it may fail to install future packages.)

As an alternative, you can create a global overlay that isn't managed by the package manager, and install packages from source there. `/opt/ros/indigo_overlay` or `/opt/ros/indigo_local` might be a good choices.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-08-08**:
Good point, I think I'll do that with the `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-08-08**:
We've used `/opt/ros/indigo/local` in the past for this type of thing, but there isn't a strong convention around it.